# How to make a loop for part of record in Ranorex

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, ranorex

I am willing to make a loop for a part of record in Ranorex. What is the best way to do it?

For example: I want to repeat same behaviour for 20 times (eg. Enter CardNr, Click on pay button).

In this case, I wan steps "10 until 12", repeated 20 times. (See the attached image).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Make steps 10-12 their own recording module (select all the steps > right-click > Move to new recording module), then set that recording modules repeat count to 20 in the recording's settings (as pictured below).

[image]

To run both recording modules together, add them to your [test suite](https://www.ranorex.com/help/latest/ranorex-studio-fundamentals/test-suite/introduction/) and run the entire test suite instead of just the recording module.